# Working with credentials encrypted credentials on Aruba / HP switches

Tags: cisco, switch, hp-procurve, aruba

I come more from a cisco back ground and there when i show the running configuration i can see the encrypted / hased local user password.

This makes it more secure to have in a automation tool where I dont have to store it in plain text.

With the aruba switchs i have it used the "password manager admin ...." comand to set a password but i cant see how to enter the password in its hased / encrypted form like i can in CISCO.

IE when you set up the user on cisco you can chose to enter a plain text, or type 5, 7 9 encrypted / hashed passsword string.

I actuly run TACACS for normal admin access this is jsut for the local admin last resorce access.

Can any one tell me if there is a simular feature on Aruba to what i am use to on CISCO.

Thank you

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can SHA1 encrypt the local password, e.g.

```
password manager admin sha1 <hash>
```

I have extensively used RSA authentication for SSH and SFTP access - imho the best option since there's no shared password. This is initially set up with

```
aaa authentication ssh enable public-key
```

You upload the public key ring to */ssh/mgr_keys* and can check if the keys are working properly using

```
show crypto client-public-key
```

Comment: I dont get the option to chose sha1, password manager admin ? just give me choise of plaintrext

Comment: What's the device type? There are (more or less) subtle differences across series and releases...

Comment: its mutiply models and ages of firmware. About 5,000 of them :) my issue with aruba / hp all different

Comment: Well, RSA pubkey authentication worked on all I've tried - 2610, 2510, 2910al, 2530.